# SQLPS/AzureRm.Profile modules stopped working on Azure VM image

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, sqlps

I have a CI build process that's been working great for months. Despite having no changes, it suddenly broke and now consistently fails with this error:

> The 'Backup-SqlDatabase' command was found in the module 'SQLPS', but
>   the module could not be loaded. For more information, run
>   'Import-Module SQLPS'.

The process provisions a new VM every time so I'm guessing it has something to do with Microsoft updates but I can't tell what. Thus far, the only way I've been able to fix it is to log in through RDP to the newly provisioned VM before the CI process starts.

I tried adding `Import-Module SQLPS` to the build script and got an even weirder error message

> Could not find file 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.format.ps1xml'

I tried `Install-Module SQLPS` and got

> No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'SQLPS'.

So I added

```
$modules = (Get-Module -Name "AzureRM" -Verbose)
$modules | Uninstall-Module -Force -Verbose
Install-Module AzureRM -Verbose -Force
Import-Module SQLPS
```

But am now getting a new error:

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.profile\3.3.1\Hyak.Common.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process."

I feel like I'm running in circles. Is this a Microsoft update or something? Can anyone tell me how to fix my AzureRM module which seems to me to be breaking my SQLPS module somehow?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling them module yet?

Comment: @Persistent13 I did try that but it supposedly couldn't find the module. I edited my question.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question, but if you want to install a SQL Server module you'll need to run `Install-Module -Name SqlServer` as SQLPS is not available on the PowerShell Gallery. However, it may still get you want you want. Be sure to remove SQLPS first otherwise you'll run into conflicts.

Comment: @Persistent13 Thanks for the suggestions but after implementing them I am receiving the same 'Could not find file ...Commands.Profile.format.ps1xml' error that I was when importing SQLPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure it out. I rewrote it to use sqlcmd and `BACKUP DATABASE`.